# prove that if: $f_0 (x)= \frac{x}{x+1}$ and $f_{n+1} (x)= f_0 ∘ f_n$  =0,1,2,3…,ℎ $f_{n} (x)= \frac{x}{(n+1)x+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

Use mathematical induction to prove that if:
$$f_0 (x)= \frac{x}{x+1}$$ and $$f_{n+1} (x)= f_0 ∘ f_n$$ for $=0,1,2,3,\ldots$, then $$f_{n} (x)= \frac{x}{(n+1)x+1}.$$

I honestly don't even know where to start with this one so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base case : $f_1 = f_0 ∘ f_0 = \frac{\frac{x}{x+1}}{\frac{x}{x+1}+1} = \frac{\frac{x}{x+1}}{\frac{2x+1}{x+1}} = \frac{x}{2x+1}$ so its true.

Assume that its true for $f_{n-1} = \frac{x}{n x+1}$

Prove for $f_n = f_0 ∘ f_{n-1}  = \frac{\frac{x}{x+1}}{n \frac{x}{x+1}+1} = \frac{\frac{x}{x+1}}{\frac{n x}{x+1}+1} =\frac{\frac{x}{x+1}}{\frac{n x+x+1}{x+1}} 
 = \frac{x}{n x+ x +1} = \frac{x}{(n+1)x+1}$

Done.

**Note** $g(x) ∘  f(x) = g(f(x)) $